# reordering rows in a databound datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a DataTable, is there a way to reorder the rows in the DataGridView and have the changes reflected in the bound DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DataView` or a `BindingSource` between the `DataTable` and the `DataGridView`, they both have a `Sort` property :

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
view.Sort = "Name ASC, Age Desc";
dataGridView.DataSource = view;
```

You can also filter the results using the `DataView.RowFilter` property (or `BindingSource.Filter`).

The `DataGridView` will automatically reflect the changes

Comment: What if there is no definitive sorting scheme? ie. I want to move the 9th row to the 1st position?

Comment: Remove the ninth row from the DataTable, and insert it at the first position

Comment: - or add a new "Order" column to the DataTable and use it for sorting. Whatever you do, always perform sorting at the DataSource side, not in the DataGridView, or you'll end up hanging yourself ;)